# Find end of a function with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a way to find the end of a method/function with regex in PHP. But i'm wondering if this is even possible.

A function obviously always end with a closing bracket `}`, but so do `if/else`, `for` and `while` statements and the likes...

Is there any way to find and replace the last bracket of a function with a regular expression?

So i should be able to replace the following:

```
public function func1 ( $someParam )
{
    if ( $someParam ) {

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

to this:

```
public function func1 ( $someParam )
{
    if ( $someParam ) {

    }
    else {

    }

}]; // <-- note the square bracket and semi-colon
```

Comment: Why would you need to this? Isn't there a design flaw if you need a program to start looking at it's own source code?

Comment: That's only theoretically possible (=no). Use the [`tokenizer`](http://php.net/tokenizer) or a [PHP parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression is the wrong tool for the job. A regex won't be able to deal with all the various nesting levels and slew of things you might find inside a function. As mario and Matt Lo suggested in the above comments, you need to use something that parses the text and determines the true structure of the code.

PHP is not a regular language that should be parsed with a regular expression, it's in BNF and should be parsed as such. (I mean, you could use regex, but you're setting yourself up for a bad time. You can also name all your variables after kittens if it tickles your fancy.)

The [tokenizer](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) mario posted is likely your best bet here, as it moves code into a syntax tree, then you can transform the tree back into code. If you have issues using it be sure to follow up with a new question. I believe the author of that library is still active on this site.